# Remove spaces around bars in PDF output

Tags: r, plot

I have a bar plot:

```
> data = c(1, 5, 3, 4)
> barplot(data, space = 0, col = 'gray', border = 0)
```

On OS X, using the default driver (Quartz), this looks like this:

[image: bar plot screenshot]

Notice how there is **no** space between the bars. However, when exporting the figure to PDF, either

1. via `quartz.save('file.pdf', type = 'pdf')` or
2. via `pdf('file.pdf', type = 'pdf')` followed by `barplot(…)`

The output looks like this:

[image: bar plot PDF export]

There are clearly discernible lines between the bars. Unfortunately, in my case this is more than just an aesthetic nuisance: I’m plotting a *lot* of pixel-thin bars, and the space between the bars is almost as big as the bars themselves, which changes the perception of the plot drastically.

Is there a way to get rid of the lines in the output? Preferably when using the `pdf` device rather than PDF `quartz` output?

Comment: quite a ugly solution but adding a negative space (`barplot(data, space = -.1, col = 'gray', border = 0)`) does the trick. Let's just hope someone can come up with a less hacky solution.

Comment: Cf. `?barplot`, set `border=NA` to omit borders. I cannot say whether this is the same as when `border=0`.

Comment: @MrGrumble one would think but I tried it as well and it doesn't chnage anything on the pdf. Largh solution though works as expected.

Comment: sometimes such lines are an artefact of the pdf viewer. I don't know if it's the case here.

Comment: @baptiste It’s not – they plots are actually postprocessed in Illustrator. The lines are visible throughout the whole process pipeline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
barplot(data, space = 0, col = 'gray', border = 'gray')
```

**EDIT: Extended answer.**

If you just define the color of border to the same than the fill, it should work. Following code produces the plot below:

```
data = c(1, 5, 3, 4)
pdf('file.pdf') 
barplot(data, space = 0, col = 'gray', border = 'gray')
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: It’s worth noting that this won’t work if you have `par(lty = 0)` set. I almost despaired because this worked in the toy example but not in my real code. Resetting `lty` solved that.