# How can I remove bar boarders in geom_histogram using the pdf device

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

I only have the problem when I try to make a pdf! Not on the default device or with png!

```
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())
data(iris)
pdf("test.pdf")
ggplot(iris,aes(x=Sepal.Length)) + geom_histogram()
dev.off()
```

[image: results from test.pdf]

What I want is what I get if I set the border color equal to the fill color.

```
pdf("test2.pdf")
ggplot(iris,aes(x=Sepal.Length)) + geom_histogram(color='grey35')
dev.off()
```

[image: Results from temp2.pdf]

Of course that solution won't generalize if I change color themes, or use the fill aesthetic.

Comment: I don't think it's actually a border, as `size = 3` (for example) doesn't make the border larger. Rather, I think it's a gap between bars that is filled when you choose to have a border by selecting a colour. Also, this is also a problem in base R (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21602316/remove-spaces-around-bars-in-pdf-output))

Comment: So maybe the solution that I'm looking for will automatically select a color for the border that is the same as the fill color.

Comment: Yes, that would work. I've cludged a solution together below, although I'm sure there's a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: Just FYI I can't reproduce the problem of the lines in the saved PDF version of the plot.  That doesn't necessarily mean much :), but if you don't have the most current version of ggplot2 you could update and see if that changes anything for you.

Comment: The issue happens under ggplot 3.2.0. My hunch is that the problem may be with the pdf device driver on linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that makes the border colour the same as the fill colour. It's not ideal, but it seems to work.

```r
# Load package
library(ggplot2)

# Load data
data(iris)

# Define gap filler function
gap_filler <- function(g){
  # Get ggplot object
  p <- ggplot_build(g)

  # Fix colour to match fill
  p$data[[1]]$colour <- p$data[[1]]$fill

  # Return
  grid::grid.draw(ggplot_gtable(p))
}

# Open PDF device
pdf("test.pdf")

# Create plot
g <- ggplot(iris,aes(x=Sepal.Length)) + geom_histogram()
g <- g + theme_bw()

# Fill gaps & plot
gap_filler(g)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.

# Close device
dev.off()
#> png 
#>   2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

And the PDF looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for showing me something about how to hack ggplot.